# Imported list with people picker matches wrong users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I'm running SharePoint Foundation 2013.

I have a list that I'm trying to migrate from one site collection to another.  I have used Export-SPWeb and also saving the list as a template (with content) via the GUI, but the list comes up on the new site collection with the people picker name matching another user's name.

I'm guessing this has to do with the AD users being imported to the new site collection at different times and they have different IDs, but that's just a guess.

Is there a good way to resolve this issue?  I still need a people picker, but not matched to the wrong name.  Thanks.

Comment: Not really, the List will use the internal ID of the source object (person) and that ID will not match the destination object (person) with the User Info List. Export-SPWeb is not high-fidelity, unfortunately. You will see lookup references break in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

People picker will resolve to the site collection's User Info Table first.  Try adding the missing user to the site.?  Also, I have the issue that we have users in 5 domains.  SharePoint is in one.  It will resolve to an account in its home domain by default.  I have to specify an alternate domain to find a specific user or utilize the search/browse function of people picker.

You could make a SP group that has the users you want and ensure the field only looks up from that group instead of from AD.

Comment: The same users appear in both sites, just with different db ID's, so I don't think that will work.  Unfortunately the list is already populated, so creating a SP group resolve the issue.